# Handle push notification with user's preferences

Tags: react-native, expo

I would like to integrate push notification to my React native app. Actually I can send my push notification without read my user's notifications preferences. What is the best pattern to handle that ? Should I store these preferences in my database then read this before send notification push ? I also heard about channel notification on Android. Should I use it ?

Comment: What do you mean by user's preferences?

Comment: Weather the user decide to receive notification push for a given channel

Comment: Do you have channel concept in your app?

Comment: If yes then you should store these preferences in your database at the server, Send notification to those users who enable receiving notification for that channel.